# Asynchronous C# app like exactly Javascript

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

In javascript we can call SetTimeout for Asynchronous operations without worrying Thread-Safe issues because javascript is single threaded and SetTimeout will not execute code block in new thread.

In C# we can use Task class in order to make a operation asynchronous like below.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> DoOperation());
```

But as far as i know that DoOperation can be happen in main thread or a new thread and Task does not let us give decision about to be new thread and in same thread.

New async feature is not equivalent of SetTimeout.

How can i achieve exactly same thing in C# app like Javascript ? Is there a way to configure Console App as single threaded(I remember such a thing)

**Edit:**
Think about below use case scenario that i am dealing. It is much simplified version.

```
class Program
{
    static BufferBlock<int> queue = new BufferBlock<int>();
    static List<int> list = new List<int>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.WhenAll(Produce(), Consume()).ContinueWith(r=> Console.WriteLine("list count: "+list.Count));

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static async Task Produce()
    {
        var random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            var value = random.Next();
            await queue.SendAsync(value);
            await Task.Delay(random.Next(1, 4));

            list.Add(value);//manipulate none thread safe object
            Console.WriteLine("value produced " + value);
        }

        queue.Complete();
    }

    public static async Task Consume()
    {
        var random = new Random();
        while (await queue.OutputAvailableAsync())
        {
            var value = await queue.ReceiveAsync();

            //consume the value
            await Task.Delay(random.Next(1, 4));

            list.Remove(value);//manipulate none thread safe object

            Console.WriteLine("value consumed " + value);
        }
    }
}
```

It is basically producer/consumer pattern and producer add values and consumers consume those values. We manipulate List object via this job and it is not thread safe.

At the end of the task list count should be 0 but it is not because 2 task accessing none thread safe List object. We can surely deal thread-safe issue differently like locking but in my use case it was unnecessary,inefficient, too many locking is hard to follow and easy to fall to deadlocks issues.

@Asad and others pointed right direction so thanks for all.

Comment: @Asad I edited question in order to clarify. Javascript is single threaded so SetTimeout is already so .. i think you misunderstand me.

Comment: Javascript has something to give control away (browser), your code does not. You can emulate this behavior though.

Comment: Trying to recreate functionality of one language into another in a 1:1 ratio is pretty much always a BAD idea. Why do you need this? If you've provided a context for your question, you'd get much better answers.

Comment: @walther is there way to tell the task run on same thread ?

Comment: If you want it to run on the same thread, don't use a task, not sure what you are asking, you want to make a multi-threaded construct act like a single threaded one? Then don't use multi-threaded constructs. Console applications are single threaded by default unless you start spawning threads.

Comment: @Freshblood Is your goal actually to run tasks on the same thread or only to ensure that there is never any more than one thread running?

Comment: @Ron Beyer I think that you don't understand differences between Asynchronous and Multi-Thread.

Comment: @Freshblood I understand it well, typically async operations (before async/await) have a BeginXXX and an EndXXX that takes an IAsyncResult. Task.Factory.StartNew queues up a task on the thread pool that may operate in the same thread, or in a separate thread. What you are asking to do seems like you want both worlds, a Task that runs on the same thread but operates at some later time after blocking I/O triggers it or some other blocking operation completes.

Comment: @Asad Any of them would be fine

Comment: I provided my use case

Comment: @Freshblood you are mixing up several concepts. Console and desktop applications *are* single-threaded unless you start new threads. `async/await` ensures that even if you *do* start an asynchronous operation, you'll be able to handle it in a synchronous, thread-safe manner - ie .NET does what you need and more. You *don't need* single-threaded operations to ensure thread-safety. Javascript's single-thread model is a limitation, not a feature. That's why web workers (among other techniques) are being introduced

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  "NET does what you need and more. You don't need single-threaded operations to ensure thread-safety" So what is the solution for this problem ? As you have seen the code hits to thread-safe issue so your solution would be to use locks ? If only a single thread handle both my producer and consumer then it is more efficient because a single thread can handle both and switch execution flows while one is in waiting state without thread safe issues.

Comment: @Freshblood posted the possible answers. I'd never use List and locking, there are other options. The simplest option is probably the ActionBlock, although different libraries address different scenarios.

Comment: @Freshblood tasks aren't threads. A Task is an *abstraction* that uses a thread from a thread pool only when executing. A Task that awaits some other task's completion doesn't use any threads. The threadpool also ensures that threads are available when your code asks for one so there is no thread creation penalty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to ensure that no more than one thread is running (and not necessarily that everything runs on the same thread), you can use an exclusive scheduler to do this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var sch = new ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair().ExclusiveScheduler;
    var tf = new TaskFactory(sch);

    var t = tf.StartNew(() => Run()).Result;
    t.Wait();
}

static async Task Run()
{
    var start = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var t = Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(_ =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I tried to log after 1 second, ended up logging after {0}", (DateTime.UtcNow - start).TotalSeconds);
    });
    Console.WriteLine("It has not yet been 1 second. I will hog the only thread available to demonstrate how I simulate JS behavior.");
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    await t;
}
```

I'm using the [`ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair.ExclusiveScheduler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.concurrentexclusiveschedulerpair.exclusivescheduler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to create a new task factory, which I will use to run my main program entry point.

If you run this program, you'll notice that even though the logging was scheduled for 1 second, it was blocked because a thread is already occupied with doing nothing (which is exactly how JS behaves). Remove the `Sleep` and the timeout callback is invoked on time.

Finally, here is how you would emulate the JS `setTimeout` behavior using single threaded async:

```
static async Task JSSetTimeout(int ms, Action callback, int waitResolution = 10)
{
    var startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    while ((DateTime.UtcNow - startTime).TotalMilliseconds < ms)
    {
        await Task.Delay(waitResolution);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    callback();
}
```

Comment: if you call tf.StartNew(() => Run()) more than than 1 time you will see that it reserves extra threads . I tested the code and unfortunately it still creates new threads.

Comment: @Freshblood You're not supposed to call `tf.StartNew` multiple times (unless you *want* multiple concurrent operations). You're supposed to do all your async work within the entrypoint you're passing to `tf.StartNew`, and the scheduler will ensure no more than one thread is ever running within that context.

Comment: @Freshblood Putting it another way, try doing whatever async stuff you want inside the `Run` method. See if you can make the degree of concurrency ever go above a single thread.

Answer (score 1):

What you want seems really funny, you're probably missing something regarding async/await. That being said, you might be able to use

[TaskFactory.StartNew Method (Func, CancellationToken, TaskCreationOptions, TaskScheduler)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782533(v=vs.110).aspx)

and pass your own task scheduler, something like

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/43000/a-taskscheduler-that-always-run-tasks-in-a-specific-thread

You'd want all your code that can cause concurrency issues using this task scheduler though (so don't run any of it on the main thread).

Comment: I provided a use case scenario, that makes sense ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for `Tasks` which happen in a single threaded manner, look to `TaskScheduler`.

Alternate methods include setting up a [`SynchronizationContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - if you're using a WPF application, this because a lot easier to access. Once obtained, just call `Post` to send your call off to the "next available time" of the UI/Main thread.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your *actual* problem is how to implement the producer/consumer structure in a thread-safe manner. It looks like you attempted to implement this using a collection that isn't thread-safe and tried to add thread-safety using techniques that come from Javascript.

There's no need of `setTimeout` to ensure thread safety. In any case, the call is equivalent to a fire-once [windows timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which always executes on an application's UI thread. `await Task.Delay()` also uses a fire-once timer internally but ensures execution resumes on its original context - on a desktop application, that is the UI thread.

Polling isn't necessary though if you can have consumers working independently. Even if you do want polling, you can implement it with one of the other timer classes and .NET's support for producer/consumer.

.NET already provides several producer/consumer implementations, and even provides the [IProducerConsumerCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287147(v=vs.110).aspx) abstraction to combine them.

1. [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a high-level abstraction that can use any collection implementing `IProducerConsumerCollection`. By default, it uses a [ConcurrentQueue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) collection to ensure thread safety without locking. The producer simply adds elements while the consumer reads items in a blocking manner. Polling isn't needed because the consumer threads simply block while waiting and respond immediately when new data is posted.
2. You can use [ConcurrentQueue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and polling on the consumer side directly, if you don't like the idea of a blocking consumer. The queue is lock-free and supports multiple concurrent readers and writers.
3. The active blocks of the TPL Dataflow library like [ActionBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) allow producers to post data to a block, and the block ensures that they are processed in a thred-safe manner using one or more concurrent tasks. By default, ActionBlock uses only one Task although this can be modified. Polling isn't needed, as the ActionBlock will call the consuming method immediately when data is available. The code can be as simple as:

```
    var myBlock=new ActionBlock(data=>DoSomething(data));
    ....
    myBlock.Post(someOtherData);
```

4. If you don't want to use an ActionBlock for processing, you can use a [BufferBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160414%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as "just" a producer/consumer buffer to allow consumers to read data independent of producers. In this case you do need to implement polling, eg with a timer
5. The worst case, something that is no longer necessary, is to use locking around an unsafe collection like `List<T>` to prevent multiple producers and consumers from modifying the collection at the same time.

Comment: Firstly BlockingCollection is blocking thread when it is waiting next item while iterating it so this is not efficient like BufferBlock which is none blocking(Asynchronous) as You may missed to see BufferBlock which i already use in the code and it is already thread safe and none blocking. The problem arises when you need to use static(shared) object between producer and consumer.

Comment: The problem is the *List*, not the buffer block. Just *don't use unsafe global objects*, there is no need to. This is a primary directive for any kind of concurrent programming (not only in .NET). Either change your flow so you pass unsafe state from one call to the next, or use a thread-safe object like `ConcurrentQueue`. TPL Dataflow was actually made makes message (state) passing a lot simpler in robotics scenarios

Comment: Moreover, "efficient" isn't self-describing. Polling is *less* efficient because it causes processing delays and results in wasted CPU cycles. Blocking wastes a thread but not CPU cycles. ActionBlock wastes neither, is simpler to use and avoids the temptation to use static objects.